# How to set a variable within calling a method - eg [... { here }]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this piece of code and tries to set the variable NotAllSaved to true but after call to the saveObject returns, the variable is false again.

```
NotAllSaved=false
[healthStore saveObject:theSample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
   if (!success){
       if (error.code==HKErrorAuthorizationDenied) {
           NotAllSaved=true;
       } else {
           ...    
       }
    }
}];
if (NotAllSaved) {
    // Does never come here
}
```

How can I set the variable so I can handle the error outside the call to SaveObject? If I try to popup an alert there, the app takes a lot of time before showing the popup.

-

Added:

Thank you Lytic and Saheb Roy, your answers (and some additional Googling) solved my problem, so the solution that works for me is this:

```
__block bool NotAllSaved=false;
dispatch_group_t theWaitGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_enter(theWaitGroup);
[HDBI.healthStore saveObject:theSample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
    if (!success){
        if (error.code==HKErrorAuthorizationDenied){
            NotAllSaved=true;
        } else {
            .. .
        }
    }
    dispatch_group_leave(theWaitGroup);
}];
dispatch_group_wait(theWaitGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
if (NotAllSaved) {
```

Comment: Have you verified that the app taking a long time to show the error isn't just the app taking a long time to execute the completion block? If it's happening asynchronously, the code in the completion block isn't being called until long after the final lines of the synchronous function (your if (NotAllSaved) statement). Try setting breakpoints on the if(!success) and if(NotAllSaved) and see which order they are executed.

Comment: I displayed an error dialog (UIAlertView) there and it was not possible to dismiss it, so by one or another reason that was not a good thing to do.

Comment: Try wrapping the call in a performOnMainThread or dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a behavior of using blocks asynchronously.

The code contained in withCompletion:{} is actually not executed until the operation queue runs the block. Which typically will happen AFTER the check if(NotAllSaved)

The error must be handled within the completion block (or could call an error handler)

For Example:

```
NotAllSaved=false
[healthStore saveObject:theSample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
            {
                if (!success)
                {
                    if (error.code==HKErrorAuthorizationDenied)
                    {
                        NotAllSaved=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ...    
                    }
                }

                if (NotAllSaved)
                {
                   // Will execute now
                }
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because this isnt a method, its a block starting with the caret symbol `^`, when you want to access any local variable inside a block, the block makes a copy of the variable or rather think of it like this, inside the block the variable is `read only`, to make the variable read write use this

`__block BOOL NotAllSaved = false`; 
Now setting this by using this `__block` (2 underscores) you call the variable by its reference